# Is there a PHP function to pull out the string between two characters?

Tags: php

Is there a PHP function that grabs the string in between two characters. For example, I want to know what is between the percent and dollar symbol:

> %HERE$

What is the function for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do that with a regex :

```
$string = 'test%HERE$glop';

$m = array();
if (preg_match('/%(.*?)\$/', $string, $m)) {
  var_dump($m[1]);
}
```

Will get you :

```
string 'HERE' (length=4)
```

Couple of notes :

- The `$` in the pattern has the be escaped, as it has a special meaning *(end of string)*
- You want to match everything : `.*`

  - that's between `%` and `$`
  - But in non-gready mode : `.*?`
- And you want that captured -- hence the `()` arround it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a regular expression to get that:

```
preg_match('/%([^$]*)\\$/', $str, $match)
```

If a match was found, `$match[0]` will contain the whole match and `$match[1]` the text between `%` and `$`.

But you can also use basic string functions like [`strpos`](http://php.net/strpos) and search for the `%` and the first `$` after that:

```
if (($start = strpos($str, '%')) !== false && ($end = strpos($str, '$', $start)) !== false) {
    $match = substr($str, $start, $end-$start);
}
```